# WAT: Web App Template

Tags: web-applications, project-template, visual-studio-2015

As I understand using [WAT](https://wat.codeplex.com/) you can wrap existing web application to make Windows Store app.

But when I tried to install it for VS 2015 Community Edition, I got the following error:

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.

Does it mean that this project template is not available anymore and I should to use Cordova instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need WAT anymore. Instead you can use [hosted web app solution](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm?WT.mc_id=16585-DEV-codeproject-article70).

You can create app by wrapping existing web site:

> Click “File -> New Project” and choose “JavaScript -> Windows ->
>   Windows Universal -> Blank App (Windows Universal)”

Answer (score 0):

The WAT web app template is not a reliable source ,,it's buggy and their is very little documentation..I would rely on a visual studio native web template for windows universal..gone are the days when you can just add your website and that's it ..build web apps with the universal API .